# Workflow was not works on child object when criteria was used parent object

Tags: workflow, tasks

I have two objects , one is parent(Account) and second one is child(Temp) and both of have master details relationship.

I have created one workflow on Temp object and used rule criteria of account object. and below is the criteria.

Account number equals 10

and checked the radio button "Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria"

whenever the workflow fires "task" will generate.

to run the workflow i have made the changes in the account number form 10 to 11 and then again 10 but workflow was not fire any of the case.

Could you please suggest if i am miss something here so due to limitation it was not working

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Eric says, changes to a parent object won't trigger DML on the child object (and hence WF on child object won't be triggered)

Using a cross-object formula field on Child that pulls in the parent's Account Number also won't work as formulas are evaluated at record retrieval time and aren't actually saved in the object - thus, no DML event.

Hence, you have two options

**Option 1 - Process Builder**

Process Builder can push a change in a parent object into every child object. This will definitely cause a DML update on the child and hence workflows will fire on the child

**Option 2 - Trigger**
An after update trigger on parent can push the changes in the parent into some or all of the child objects. Those child objects touched will also cause Workflow to ensure

Answer (score 1):

Workflow rules on child objects do not fire when the parent is updated.

In order for the workflow rule on the child to be executed the object where the WFR is defined on will need to be edited / touched

> Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it's edited
>   to subsequently meet criteria

Record and it refer to the object the WFR is attached, in your case the "Temp" object

Comment: I have updated the child object(Temp) record accordingly but it's not fire

Comment: You may need to use a formula on the Temp object to pull in the value from Account. I am not sure if using the subsequently trigger on a cross object will fire the WFR. Never done that before. I would think it would be problematic as the field is never changed when the child is updated, rather it just is what it is....I am sure someone else may have done this before or can clarify

Comment: I have also tried with formula that retrieves the value from the Account object and used that formula on workflow but it's not working same result as earlier...

but wanted to say that when i select "Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and every time it's edited" then workflow will fire whenever the Temp object records were edited and task was generated

Comment: Hi Team could you please update on the above issue